# Full Text Search with Spring Data ElasticSearch

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data

Is it possible to use a full text search using Spring Data Elastic Search?

I can't seem to find examples in the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the answer above yes you can use spring data elasticsearch to accomplish almost everything you can do with elasticsearch.

If you are looking for the examples then have a look at spring data elasticsearch sample project which have some basic examples how to create, index and search into elasticsearch using your spring powered application(entities).

https://github.com/BioMedCentralLtd/spring-data-elasticsearch-sample-application

HTH

Comment: Do I need to create the entities through Spring? what if I already have existing Entities Data in ElasticSearch? How will I map them?

Comment: have a look on the above example(link), in which it is shown how to create, save and search into elasticsearch using entities

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Elastic Search is mostly intended to inject your elasticsearch client dependency, which is then used to perform queries.

Once you have the client object (after adding to appcontext.xml and autowiring) you then have a standard Java elasticsearch client object and can find examples here:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/search.html